# Error when converting array to JSON in JQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, stringify

I have a number of strings:

```
var a = ['one','two'];
var b = ['three','four'];
var c = ['five'];
var d = ['six','seven','eight']; 
var e = ['nine','ten','eleven'];

a_str = JSON.stringify(a);
b_str = JSON.stringify(b);
c_str = JSON.stringify(c);
d_str = JSON.stringify(d);
e_str = JSON.stringify(e);

console.log(a_str);
```

From Inspect > Console, I get:

```
["one","two"]
> typeof(a)
<- "object"
>
```

How would I use AJAX to pass those variables to the backend (python/Flask)?

Comment: *Is this a JSON object?* - No, there are no such things as *JSON* objects. They are just JavaScript objects.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek how would I use AJAX to send those variables to the back end (Python/Flask)?

Comment: Using `JSON.stringify` works fine. You can pass them as a string then decode them on the backend. That said, that's is a different question than the one posted.

Comment: You don't need to JSON.stringify them at all. Simply use the array as data, jquery handles the rest

Comment: @baao is there an example of passing arrays to Flask?

Comment: Yeah, just take the one from jquery's documentation http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: `$.ajax({
        url:'your url',
        data:{
            a,b,c,d,e
        },
        type:'post'
    }).done(res => console.log(res));`